# C++ modulus requires cast of subtraction between two *un*signed bytes to work, why?

Tags: c++, arduino, modulo, modulus

The following Arduino (C++) code

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  byte b1 = 12;
  byte b2 = 5;
  const byte RING_BUFFER_SIZE = 64;

  byte diff = b2 - b1;
  byte diff2 = (byte)(b2 - b1) % RING_BUFFER_SIZE; //<---NOTE HOW THE (byte) CAST IS *REQUIRED* TO GET THE RIGHT RESULT!!!!

  Serial.println(b1);
  Serial.println(b2);
  Serial.println(RING_BUFFER_SIZE);
  Serial.println(diff);
  Serial.println(diff2);
}

void loop()
{      
}
```

produces the expected:

```
12
5
64
249
57 //<--correct answer
```

Whereas without the "(byte)" cast as shown here:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  byte b1 = 12;
  byte b2 = 5;
  const byte RING_BUFFER_SIZE = 64;

  byte diff = b2 - b1;
  byte diff2 = (b2 - b1) % RING_BUFFER_SIZE; //<---(byte) cast removed

  Serial.println(b1);
  Serial.println(b2);
  Serial.println(RING_BUFFER_SIZE);
  Serial.println(diff);
  Serial.println(diff2);
}

void loop()
{      
}
```

it produces:

```
12
5
64
249
249 //<--wrong answer
```

Why the difference? Why does the modulo operator ONLY work with the explicit cast?

Note: "byte" = "uint8_t"

Comment: See: integer promotions

Comment: I'll research it. Is what you see above completely expected behavior? Or does it mess programmers up all the time?

Comment: Can you show us the without code pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5 - 12` gives `-7` (an `int`).  So your code does `-7 % 64`.

Mathematically we would expect this to give `57`. However, in C and C++, `%` for negative numbers it doesn't do what you might expect mathematically. Instead it satisfies the following equation:

```
(a/b) * b + a%b == a
```

Now, `(-7)/64` gives `0` because C and C++ use truncation-towards-zero for integer division of negative-positive.  Therefore `-7 % 64` evaluates to `-7`.

Finally, converting `-7` to `uint8_t` gives `249`.

When you write `(byte)-7 % 64` you are actually doing `249 % 64` giving the expected answer.

---

Regarding the behaviour of `b2 - b1`: all integer arithmetic is done in at least `int` precision; for each operand of `-`, if it is a narrower integer type than `int` it is first promoted to `int` (leaving the value unchanged).  Further conversions may occur if the types differ after this promotion (which they don't in this case).

In code, `b2 - b1` means `(int)b2 - (int)b1` yielding an `int`; there is no way to specify doing the operation in lower precision.

Comment: since `b2` and `b1` were both unsigned, I expected a proper "underflow," just like you get overflow to zero if you add 1 to a uint8_t 255. I suppose subtraction rules are different than addition, even when both numbers are *un*signed?

Comment: @GabrielStaples added section explaining that

Comment: The rationale is perhaps historical: on the first C implementations, `a - b` it would have just loaded the values into word-sized registers and invoked the CPU instruction for subtraction.  Instead of jumping through hoops to simulate a lower-precision operation not supported in the hardware. Later standardization then couldn't break programs that relied on this behaviour.

Comment: @Gabriel Staples: "Unsignedness" of small types is lost when they get promoted to `signed int`. The only way to make unsigned arithmetic to "strick" is to use `unsigned int` or larger types.

Comment: `%` is **remainder**, not modulus. The value of the remainder depends on how the result of division involving negative numbers is rounded. A negative remainder occurs when a negative quotient gets rounded toward zero. (In a burst of revisionism, this rule was changed recently, in effect requiring rounding down, which gives non-negative remainders).

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic operations want to operate on an `int` or larger.  So, your `byte`'s are being promoted to integers before they are subtracted -- and, you're likely getting actual `int`'s, which C/C++ is OK with because they can hold the entire range of `byte`.

If the result of the subtraction is cast back down to `byte`, it gives you the expected overflow behavior.  However, if you omit the cast in the `diff2` calculation, you're doing the modulus on a *negative* `int`.  And, because C/C++ signed division rounds towards zero, the signed modulus has the same sign as the dividend.

The first misstep here is to expect subtraction to act directly on your `byte` type, or to translate your unsigned `byte` into an unsigned `int`.  The cascading problem is to overlook the behavior of C++ signed division (which is understandable if you don't know that you should expect signed arithmetic to be an issue in the first place).

Note that, if your `RING_BUFFER_SIZE` were not a power of two, the division wouldn't work correctly for cases like this anyway.  And, since it is a power of two, note that:

```
(b2 - b1)&(RING_BUFFER_SIZE-1)
```

should work correctly.

And finally (as suggested in the comment), the right way to do a ring-buffer subtract would be to make sure `b1 < RING_BUFFER_SIZE` (which makes sense for a ring buffer operation), and use something like:

```
(b2>b1)? b2 - b1 : RING_BUFFER_SIZE + b2 - b1
```

Comment: `b2 < b1 ? RING_BUFFER_SIZE - b1 + b2 : b2 - b1` would solve the problem without relying on the power-of-2 size

Comment: Yep, something like that would be the preferred way to do a ring-buffer subtract.

Comment: Added a version of M.M's comment into the answer